# What kind of Parity Check Matrices have maximum number of 1's in each column with girth greater than or equal to 6?

Tags: coding-theory

I am looking for a parity check matrix $H\in \{0,1\}^{m\times n}$ ($m<n$), with the maximum number of 1's in each column with girth greater than or equal to $6$.
I have come across array codes that are of girth $6$, but I am not satisfied with the number of 1's in each column. I would like the number of 1's to be higher than array codes. Does anybody know such a construction of parity check matrices?

Comment: I'm confused. The way I see it (using $H$ as the incidence matrix of check vertices and information vertices, LDPC code style) you could take $H$ to be all ones, and have girth four. Don't know about how you use $H$, but in coding theory we often want to prevent short cycles, girth 8 or higher. [Girth 4 is as low as it can go](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3126949/11619), so you aren't really asking for anything??

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ; Sorry for the mistake in my original question. I am looking for parity check matrices of girth 6 or higher. I am searching for a column regular parity check matrix with low coherence. Please read my original question. Are you familiar with array codes? Array codes are column regular with a girth equal to 6. Can we talk in chat?